# Qt c++ .arg error in string

Tags: c++, qt

I have been getting the error:  request for member 'arg' in '("Student number:%1 Module Code: %2 Mark: %3")', which is of non-class type 'const char [43]

can't figure out why I'm getting this error

here is the function that produces the error:

```
void StudentForm::displayForm(){
    QMessageBox box;
    box.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    stuNum = stuEdt->text().toInt();
    mark = markSbx->text().toInt();
    modCode = codeEdt->text();
    QString t = ("Student number:%1 Module Code: %2 Mark: %3").arg(stuNum).arg(modCode).arg(mark);
    box.setText(t);
    box.exec();
}
```

let me know if I need to put more of the code up etc.
Thanks

Comment: You're calling `arg` as if it was a member of the string literal.

Comment: ok, how would I do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QString t = tr("Student number:%1 Module Code: %2 Mark: %3").arg(stuNum).arg(modCode).arg(mark);
```

`tr` tries to look up a translated version of the string first - it's a good habit for user-visible strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
QString t = QString("Student number:%1 Module Code: %2 Mark: %3").arg(stuNum).arg(modCode).arg(mark);
```